# jQuery animate() left position in Google Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a simple animation where element after being appended to the container is sliding in from the left side like so:

```
$('#container').append(
$('<div class="item" style="left:-300px;top:0"></div>').animate({ left : 0 }, 300)
);
```

Container has the overflow hidden and width 300px.
The appended 'item' element has also 300px width and is outside of the container when appended, then should slide in until it reaches 'left : 0'.

It works in Firefox, but Google Chrome and Safari simply displays it in the container without sliding it in.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you thought of using `display:none;` and `slideToggle()` instead? Might make things a little easier.

Comment: How would you do it with slideToggle() ? You can't specify the position with this method.

Comment: You are totally right, I mixed up 2 things here, what I was actually thinking of was using `animate({width:'show'})` as seen here: http://bueltge.de/test/jquery_horizontal_slide.php - sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you need to add element befor animating:

```
$('<div class="item" style="left:-300px;top:0"></div>').appendTo('#container').animate({ left : 0 }, 300)
```

Comment: You're absolutely right - I've just tried to do it after appending and it works fine.